# I can use MVT on $\lim _{_{x\rightarrow \infty }}\int _0^x\:e^{t^2}dt$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If I can use MVT: $\lim _{_{x\rightarrow \infty }}\int _0^x\:e^{t^2}dt=x\cdot f\left(c\right)$ when $x\rightarrow \infty ,\:c\rightarrow \infty $ so we'll have to evaluate $\lim _{x\to \infty }x\cdot f\left(x\right)=divergent$.

I know it is divergent, but I saw in this case when I apply MVT, I obtain the correct answer, and I don't know if it is possible to use here MVT, is it?

If this work on this case and we can use MVT, it means also will work on this: $\lim _{x\to \infty }\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^x\:f\left(t\right)dt$, where $f\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{\left(1+t^2\right)\left(1+t^3\right)}$.

But if we apply the same procedure, we don't obtain the correct answer:

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^x\:f\left(t\right)dt=lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{x^2-1}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{\left(1+c^2\right)\left(1+c^3\right)}$, $c=c_x\in \left[\frac{1}{x},x\right]$  which is equal with 0, but the correct answer is $\frac{\pi }{4}$, and this makes me think that we can not use neither here: $\lim _{_{x\rightarrow \infty }}\int _0^x\:e^{t^2}dt$

---

So, in which cases work to use MVT ? when we use MVT?

Comment: What do you get for $c$ when you "apply the same procedure"? $\;$

Comment: $\int _{\frac{1}{x}}^x\:f\left(t\right)dt=\frac{x^2-1}{x}\cdot f\left(c\right),\:c\in \left[\frac{1}{x},\:x\right]$,  where $c\in \left(\frac{1}{x},\:x\right)$ and than $x\rightarrow \infty ,\:c\rightarrow \infty $

Comment: Oh, I was also missing something else. $\:$ You used $\hspace{.04 in}f(x)$ instead of $\hspace{.04 in}f(c)$ near the beginning of your post. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer I use $f\left(x\right)$ instead $f\left(c\right)$, because I thought are equal: $x\rightarrow \infty ,\:c\rightarrow \infty \:\lim _{x\to \infty }f\left(x\right)=\lim _{c\to \infty }f\left(c\right)$, and why we can't use this change?

Comment: Their _limits_ are equal; they are usually not equal. $\;\;\;\;$ Consider $\: x\cdot \frac1x \:$ and $\: x\cdot \frac1{2\cdot x} \;$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: you say "Their limits are equal" , and we have to find limit... so I don't understand why we can't use ... look at first case, what is wrong there? suppose $f\left(x\right)\ne \:f\left(c\right)$ as you say, but when we evaluate their limits are equal...

Comment: ... and it so happens that the limits of $x$ times them are also equal. $\:$ However, I don't see any reason to believe that happens in the other case. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: accidentally I try to use MVT to see what happens because I don't believe that will work... and don't understand what's wrong in first case ... but in the second I'm surely don't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xf\left(c\right)
 $$ with $c=c\left(x\right)\in\left[0,x\right]
 $ but this not mean that you can use $f\left(x\right)$ instead of $f\left(c\left(x\right)\right)
 $. For example in the first case we can use the fact that $f\left(c\left(x\right)\right)\geq1
 $, hence $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xf\left(c\left(x\right)\right)\geq\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x=\infty.
 $$

Comment: But we can't say: $\lim _{x\to \infty }x\cdot f\left(c\right)=\lim _{x\to \infty }x\cdot \lim _{c\to \infty }f\left(c\right)=\infty $ ?

Comment: I use $f\left(x\right)$ instead $f\left(c\right)$, because I thought are equal: $x\rightarrow \infty ,\:c\rightarrow \infty \:\lim _{x\to \infty }f\left(x\right)=\lim _{c\to \infty }f\left(c\right)$, and why we can't use this change?

Comment: @Lucas $c$ is a function of $x$. If you change the value of $x$ in your integrals, we have a different $c$. But you haven't an explicit for of $c(x)$, so you can't conclude as you said.

Comment: if we had  $\int _0^3\:$  we can say that c not depend of x?

Comment: You can say that exists some $c\in[0,3]$ such that $\int_{0}^{3}f\left(t\right)dt=3f\left(c\right).$

Comment: If you see $z$ is a function of $x$ in that answer. About your question, yes in that case is not a function of $x$ because it's a number (is the case $x=3$). What I mean is that the choice of $c$ is linked to the range of integration. If you change the range, $c$ change. In this sense $c$ is a function of $x$ in your case (because you have $x$ in your range).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23055/discussion-between-marco-cantarini-and-lucas).

Comment: fully agree with what you said, but we can say that $\frac{1}{x}\int _0^xe^{t^2}\:dx=f\left(c\right)\:$ ? ( I divided by x ) and when $x\rightarrow 0,\:c\rightarrow 0$ which involving $\lim _{c\to \infty }f\left(c\right)=\infty $ ?

Answer (score 0):

What the MVT tells us is that for some $0\lt c(x)\lt x$, we have
$$
\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=xe^{c(x)^2}\tag{1}
$$
Since all we know is that $0\lt c(x)\lt x$, we only know that $\liminf\limits_{x\to\infty}e^{c(x)^2}\ge1$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\liminf_{x\to\infty}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
&\ge\liminf_{x\to\infty}x\cdot\liminf_{x\to\infty}e^{c(x)^2}\\
&\ge\infty\cdot1\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Inequality $(2)$ implies that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\infty\tag{3}
$$